# How to upload a folder on SageMaker Notebooks

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, directory, upload, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to upload a folder on SageMaker. However, I cannot select any folders, I need to go through the files and upload them one by one. Is there any way to upload the whole directory from local computer to SageMaker?

Comment: Do you mean SageMaker Studio ?

Answer (score 4):

zip the folder in local, upload it as a zip file and unzip it in Sagemaker terminal

Answer (score 0):

Just add more info to help save some time. Assume you have a folder locally called `pytorch-mnist`, and you want to upload files inside except for `.venv` sub folder. You can zip by:

```bash
zip -r pytorch-mnist.zip pytorch-mnist \
    -x 'pytorch-mnist/.venv/*'
```

Note do not miss `'` in the command.

Next, in SageMaker's JupterLab, open a terminal and run to unzip

```bash
cd SageMaker
unzip pytorch-mnist.zip
```

Now you should be good!